# invoking RTCPeerConnection.updateIce() in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I try to invoke RTCPeerConnection.updateICe() in Chrome. I have Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m on Windows XP. But I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified.". The arguments of updateIce are empty. The empty arguments is valid according to http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/. I also try to use {iceServers: [{ username: "...", credential: "...", url: "..." }]} as first argument. But the result is same.

The RTCPeerConnection is in "connected" state on the moment of invoking.

What could be the problem?